# Splitting and converting a string column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am processing outputs from a piece of software that provides co-ordinates as an x, y, z triple in a single column. Is there any way to split the string out into its three separate parts and convert to floats in one fell swoop? For example, I know that I can do the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': {0: 3864, 1: 3864, 2: 3864, 3: 3864, 4: 3864},
                   'COORDFRONT': {0: '787.547 238.639 0.000', 1: '787.141 238.847 0.000', 2: '786.729 239.057 0.000', 3: '786.310 239.271 0.000', 4: '785.886 239.488 0.000'},
                   'COORDREAR': {0: '803.545 230.467 0.000', 1: '803.139 230.675 0.000', 2: '802.727 230.885 0.000', 3: '802.309 231.099 0.000', 4: '801.884 231.316 0.000'}})

df['Front_x'], df['Front_y'], df['Front_z'] = df['COORDFRONT'].str.split(' ').str
```

To separate out the three strings, but trying for example

```
df['COORDFRONT'].str.split(' ').astype(float)
```

returns a `ValueError`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with `expand=True` for `DataFrame` and assign to new columns in subset by double `[]`:

```
df[['Front_x', 'Front_y', 'Front_z']] = df['COORDFRONT'].str.split(expand=True).astype(float)
print (df)
              COORDFRONT              COORDREAR    ID  Front_x  Front_y  \
0  787.547 238.639 0.000  803.545 230.467 0.000  3864  787.547  238.639   
1  787.141 238.847 0.000  803.139 230.675 0.000  3864  787.141  238.847   
2  786.729 239.057 0.000  802.727 230.885 0.000  3864  786.729  239.057   
3  786.310 239.271 0.000  802.309 231.099 0.000  3864  786.310  239.271   
4  785.886 239.488 0.000  801.884 231.316 0.000  3864  785.886  239.488   

   Front_z  
0      0.0  
1      0.0  
2      0.0  
3      0.0  
4      0.0
```

If no `NaN`s values in column is possible use `list comprehension`:

```
L = [x.split() for x in df['COORDFRONT'].values.tolist()]
df[['Front_x', 'Front_y', 'Front_z']] = pd.DataFrame(L).astype(float)
```

Comment: Knew it was something small I was missing! Thanks very much.

Comment: @asongtoruin - Glad can help!

Answer (score 1):

This is one way:

```
df['Front_x'], df['Front_y'], df['Front_z'] = list(zip(*[list(map(float, i)) for i in \
                                                   df['COORDFRONT'].str.split(' ')]))
```

**Result**

```
df.dtypes

# COORDFRONT     object
# COORDREAR      object
# ID              int64
# Front_x       float64
# Front_y       float64
# Front_z       float64
# dtype: object
```

**Explanation**

- `map` each row of string values to `float` from your `split` results.
- Apply `zip(*...)` in order to output as 3 arrays required to assign to 3 series.

**Performance**

For better performance on large dataframes, use [@jezrael's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49047277/9209546). Some benchmarking results below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': {0: 3864, 1: 3864, 2: 3864, 3: 3864, 4: 3864},
                   'COORDFRONT': {0: '787.547 238.639 0.000', 1: '787.141 238.847 0.000', 2: '786.729 239.057 0.000', 3: '786.310 239.271 0.000', 4: '785.886 239.488 0.000'},
                   'COORDREAR': {0: '803.545 230.467 0.000', 1: '803.139 230.675 0.000', 2: '802.727 230.885 0.000', 3: '802.309 231.099 0.000', 4: '801.884 231.316 0.000'}})

def jp(df):
    df['Front_x'], df['Front_y'], df['Front_z'] = list(zip(*[list(map(float, i)) for i in df['COORDFRONT'].str.split(' ')]))
    return df

def jez(df):
    df[['Front_x', 'Front_y', 'Front_z']] = df['COORDFRONT'].str.split(expand=True).astype(float)
    return df

# df = pd.concat([df]*100)
%timeit jp(df)   # 2.2ms
%timeit jez(df)  # 2.94ms

# df = pd.concat([df]*10000
%timeit jp(df)   # 154ms
%timeit jez(df)  # 127ms
```

Comment: +1 for a solution that works, but I'll mark the other one as the answer for the mentioned efficiency. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, I agree, @jezrael's solution is better. I've added some benchmarking to illustrate this.

Comment: @jpp - I add another solution which in my opinion will be your very favourite, because pure python list comprehension. If want, you can add it to timings.